# Prove that the funtion f: $G\rightarrow G$, defined by $f(x)=x^k$, $x \in G$ is a permutation of $G$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Help me with this exercise, 
I could not do it :(

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ and let $k$ be an integer relatively prime to $n$. Prove that the function f: $G \rightarrow G$, defined by $f(x)=x^k$, $x \in G$ is a  permutation of $G$.

Comment: **Hint:** A map on a set is called a permutation on that set iff the map is bijective. Can you prove that $f\colon G\to G$ is a bijection?

Comment: I could only prove it is one to one ,, I need to prove that it is surjective..

Comment: An injective function on a finite set is...

Comment: We can use the fact that an injective map on a finite set is also surjective. But if we need to explicitly show that $f$ is surjective, recall that since $\gcd(k,n)=1$, if $G=\langle a\rangle$, then $G=\langle a^k\rangle$. For any element $y\in G$, there exists $p\in\Bbb Z$ such that $y=(a^k)^p=(a^p)^k$, so we have $x=a^p\in G$ such that $f(x)=y$. This shows that $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

We shall prove that if $\gcd(k,|\mathrm{G}|)=1$ and $\mathrm{G}$ is a finite abelian group, then $f(x)=x^k$ is a permutation of $\mathrm{G}$.

First we shall prove that $f(x)$ is a $1-1$ function. Let $x,y\in\mathrm{G}$ and suppose that $f(x)=f(y)$, that is $x^k=y^k$. Since $\mathrm{G}$ is abelian, it follows that $(xy^{-1})^k=1_\mathrm{G}$. Hence $\mathrm{ord}(xy^{-1})\mid k$. Since $\mathrm{ord}(xy^{-1})\mid|\mathrm{G}|$, it follows that $\mathrm{ord}(xy^{-1})|\gcd(k,|\mathrm{G}|)$. But $\gcd(k,|\mathrm{G}|)=1$, so $\mathrm{ord}(xy^{-1})=1$. Thus $xy^{-1}=1_\mathrm{G}$, that is $x=y$, as required.

Next we shall prove that $f(x)$ in onto $\mathrm{G}$. From the first part, we know that $f(x)$ is a $1-1$ function from $\mathrm{G}$ to itself. Since $\mathrm{G}$ is finite, it follows that that $\mathrm{G}=\mathrm{im}(f)$, as required.